# Swift How to display from .text file data on label

Tags: swift, label, uilabel

The 1st and 2nd images I can have successfully read and write my thisdata.txt file but I can only print the message

and I want to make the label displaying the text from thisdata.text

How should I do that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E94df.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nntOL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOIiz.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dznld.png

Comment: `yourUILabel.text = readStringProject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign `string` to your `data` label. Just as:

```
data.text = readString // If you need to print 'readString'
data.text = readStringProject // If you need to print 'readStringProject'
```

---

```
    var readString = ""
    do {
        readString = try String(contentsOfFile: fileURL)
        data.text = readString
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("failed to read file")
        print(error)
    }
```